# PrivateKeyPath Where is it located

Tags: .net, intuit-partner-platform, x509, customer-account-data-api

I am using the Intuit Customer Account data API and have successfully created an x.509 certificate and uploaded.  I can use the API explorer properly through Intuit's website but cannot get the AggCatDotNet example sites to work.  In the web.config I have filled in key values SAMLIdentity provider and password but cannot figure out how to access my private key through PrivateKeyPath.  I have tried installing in the cert store under personal and machine stores as well as placed it in the App_Data folder and nothing works.

Any information that could be provided regarding the PrivateKeyPath would be great!

key="PrivateKeyPath" value="??????????"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is the physical path on the machine to the private key file

```
<add key="PrivateKeyPath" value="c:\MyCerts\MyCadCert.pfx" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in your project's runtime classpath ?

In JAVA, I did the same and it worked fine

[image]

intuit-aggcat-config.xml (from JAVA sample app)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<intuit-config>
    <saml>
        <keystoreFile>aggcatkeystore.jks</keystoreFile>
        <keystorePassword>abc***</keystorePassword>
        <keyPassword>abc***</keyPassword>
        <certAlias>testaggcat</certAlias>
    </saml>
</intuit-config>
```

I'll have a look at the .net sample soon. If I get something, then I'll post my findings here.

Thanks